# Не работает хендлер в aiogram

Tags: python, sqlite, aiogram

```
@dp.message_handler(text = 'Да')
async def ban(message: types.Message):
    cur.execute("DELETE FROM podpiska WHERE oplata = 0")
    base.commit()
```

указывает на букву "d" в слове "def" и говорит, что invalid syntax

```
import config
import json

from aiogram import Bot, types
from aiogram.dispatcher import Dispatcher
from aiogram.utils import executor
import sqlite3 as sq
import datetime

bot = Bot(token=config.TOKEN)
dp = Dispatcher(bot)

global base, cur
base = sq.connect('accounts.db')
cur = base.cursor()
    
@dp.message_handler(commands = ['start'])
async def dobavlenie(message: types.Message):
    #base = sq.connect('accounts.db')
    #cur = base.cursor()
    base.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS podpiska(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, date INTEGER, oplata INTEGER)')
    if datetime.date.today().day >= 29:
        dt = 28
    else:
        dt = datetime.date.today().day
    params = ( message.from_user.id, dt, 0)
    cur.execute('INSERT INTO podpiska VALUES (?, ?, ?)', params)
    base.commit()
    print(cur.execute('SELECT FROM podpiska WHERE oplata = 0')

@dp.message_handler(text = 'Да')
async def ban(message: types.Message):
    cur.execute("DELETE FROM podpiska WHERE oplata = 0")
    base.commit()
    
@dp.message_handler()
async def privet(message: types.Message):
    kd = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    yes = types.KeyboardButton('Да')
    no = types.KeyboardButton('Нет')
    kd.add(yes)
    
    await message.reply('бан?', reply_markup=kd)
executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

@MrKey8840, возможно у вас проблемы с данными строками:

```
cur.execute("DELETE FROM podpiska WHERE oplata = 0")
base.commit()
```

Comment: всё с ними вроде нормально, раньше работали

Comment: можешь предоставить фулл код без, токена и другой личной инфы бота?

Comment: предоставил нраов

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте заменить

```
from aiogram import Bot, types
from aiogram.dispatcher import Dispatcher
from aiogram.utils import executor
```

на

```
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types
```